# How to make ScrollView horizontally scrollable in a UWP app?

Tags: scrollviewer, uwp

Developing a Windows 10 UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app here...
I have a long text and I don't want to wrap it in several lines. I want it to be long so that the end user can horizontally scroll to see the entire text in one line.

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" Width="Auto">

<TextBlock Text="This is a long text that I don't want it to be wrapped in multiple lines. I want it to be horizontally long so the user can horizontally scroll to see the text"

Margin="50, 50, 0, 0"></TextBlock>

</ScrollViewer>
```

But when I run the app the text is cut off on the right edge and I cannot scroll it horizontally to see the rest of the text.
Is there a way to achieve that using a ScrollView with some additional attributes?
Here is the screen shot how the app looks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting an absolute width?

Comment: Yes, with Width="200" (and any other value) it doesn't scroll...

Comment: Is that on the Scrollviewer, or the Textblock?

Comment: Wherever I put it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to also set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` on the `ScrollViewer`.

**[ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209549)**

> Gets or sets a value that determines how manipulation input influences
>   scrolling behavior on the horizontal axis.

**[ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility.aspx)**

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a horizontal ScrollBar
>   should be displayed.